# 自作アプリをGooglePlayストアに公開し、アップデート版を上げたいのですがKeyStore作成のところで躓いてできそうにありません

Tags: android, eclipse

ご無沙汰しています。
自作アプリの完成につきましては、大変お世話になりました。
無事GooglePlayストアに公開し、バグがあったので修正版を上げたいのですが、ストアに公開したときの電子署名がPCには残っておらずアップデートできずに困っております。
もし復元が可能ならその方法を教えていただけると助かります。
この場合、ストアに公開しているものを非公開にして、もう一度別に作って公開するしかないのでしょうか？

またEclipseでapkファイルを作るときに既存のKeyStoreのものでつくりたいのですが、
いつもエイリアスのところが空白で毎回毎回どうしても違う電子署名で作成しないといけなくなります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ホームページを見てエクスポートから作成しているのですが毎回上記の画像でエイリアス（もちろん作成しているときには記入済み）が選択できずに何か解決策はないでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

お騒がせして大変申し訳ございませんでした。
回答を待っていましたが、ネットで調べて自己解決しました。
これからはもう少し良く調べてから質問致します。

ロケーションの部分をxxx.keystoreに設定することでapkファイル生成の際エイリアス欄に設定したものが表示されました。
閲覧有り難うございます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]